# Is ${\lim\limits_{x \to 0}} \frac{f(x^2+1)}{x^2+2} = {\lim\limits_{t \to 1}} \frac{f(t)}{2}$ always true?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

> Is ${\lim\limits_{x \to 0}} \frac{f(x^2+1)}{x^2+2} = {\lim\limits_{t \to 1}} \frac{f(t)}{2}$ always true?

---

My math teachers were arguing today if the statement is always true. One teacher gave a counterexample of where $f(x) = \sqrt{x-1}$. Eventually, they said that it came down to different textbook definitions of continuity and limits. Is there any other reasoning to prove this to be true or false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your limit approach is off.

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x^2+1)}{x^2+2} \neq \lim_{t \to 1} \frac{f(t)}{2} $$

Rather

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x^2+1)}{x^2+2} = \lim_{t \to 1^+} \frac{f(t)}{2} $$

Since as $x\to 0$, $(x^2+1) \to 1$, but also $x^2+1 > 1$ for all $x\neq 0$.

It doesn't make sense to write

$$ \lim_{t \to 1^-} \frac{f(t)}{2} $$

in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Consider for example a piecewise function $f(x) = 0$ for $x<1$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $x \ge 1$.  Then the left hand side is defined and equal to $1/3$, but the right hand side is not defined.

If right hand limit exists then indeed they are equal though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does come down to the definition of continuity and limits, but most imporantly it comes down to the definition of a function. Some functions are not defined everywhere. A good example is $\ f(x) = \sqrt{x}\ $ which is well defined as a real valued function **only** if $\ x\ $ is a non-negative real number. The usual definition of limits only require using the values in the **domain** of a function. In this particular case, the domain is $\ [0,\infty).\ $ Thus, by usual definition, $\ f()\ $ is continuous at $\ x=0\ $ because $\ \lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0+} f(x) = 0.\ $

For the example in the question the left limit only uses values of $\ f(x)\ $ for $\ x\ge 1\ $ and the function may have arbitrary values for $\ x<1.\ $ The right limit appears to be a two-sided limit at $\ x=1.\ $ If the domain of the function $\ f()\ $ was $\ [1,\infty)\ $ then the two limits would be the same, but without knowing the domain of the function and its values for $\ x<1\ $ it is not valid to equate the two limits.

Answer (score 1):

$${\lim_{x \to 0}} \frac{f(x^2+1)}{x^2+2} \overset{?}{=} {\lim\limits_{t \to 1}} \frac{f(t)}{2}$$

- If $f$ is continuous at $b$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}g(x)=b, \quad$ then
  $\quad\lim_{x \to a}f(g(x))=f(\lim_{x \to a}g(x)) = f(b)$.

Let $F(x) = \dfrac{f(x)}{x+1}$. Then $F(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$ if and only if $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=1$.

So, suppose that $\mathbf{\text{$\mathbf{f(x)}$ is continuous at $\mathbf{x=1}$}}$.

Let $G(x)=x^2+1$. Then 
$${\lim_{x \to 0}} \frac{f(x^2+1)}{x^2+2} 
   = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}F(G(x))
   =F(\lim_{x \to 0}G(x)) 
    = \dfrac{f(1)}{2}
    = \lim_{t \to 1}\frac{f(t)}{2}$$